# File creation/modification time in remote server

Tags: php, samba, opendir

I've got this code:

```
$cntx = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'smb' => array(
            'username' => 'me',
            'password' => 'mypass'
        )
    )
);

$dir = 'smb://192.168.100.222/MY_FOLDER$';
if ($lst = opendir($dir, $cntx)) {
    while (($file = readdir($lst)) !== false) {
        if (substr($file, -3) == 'PDF') {
            ...
```

I need to get each $file creation time to compare with files in my machine.
There's other machine I need to access, how can I have this file creation info in original server?

filemtime and filectime does not work in this case...
I have no alternative ways.

Comment: You need to use an SMB client library, not the generic file functions.

Comment: If you mount the remote share with cifs-tools so that it looks like a local directory, times are preserved and you can use filemtime() or DirectoryIterator.

Comment: Barmar and Alex, can you show me how? Maybe a simple code...
I cannot write sucessfully a code with SMB library, I get always error 10 that does not appear in error list...

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-cifs-windows-share-on-linux/